# How to get device language in sencha touch or architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am developing an app for IOS & Android with Sencha and I was wondering how to retrieve the language the device (regardless of the os) using Sencha touch or architect. Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
navigator.language
```

you can also try this on chrome developers tools:

```
 console.log(navigator.language);
```